# Read JSP page and Write HTML file UTF-8 issuses

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, jsoup

i want read JSP page and write it to HTML page. I have 3 method in parse class. first `readHTMLBody()`, second `WriteNewHTML()`, third `ZipToEpub()`.
When I called this method in parse class, all method work. But called in JSP or webservice UTF-8 character looks like "?" in `readHTMLBody()`. How can I fix it?

```
  public String readHTMLBody() {
    try {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/Library/part.jsp";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse((new URL(url)).openStream(), "utf-8", url);
        String body = doc.html();
        Elements title = doc.select("xxx");
        linkURI = title.toString();
        linkURI = linkURI.replaceAll("<xxx>", "");
        linkURI = linkURI.replaceAll("</xxx>", "");
        linkURI = linkURI.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        resultBody = body;
        resultBody = resultBody.replaceAll("part/" + linkURI + "/assets/", "assets/");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    return resultBody;
}
```

Comment: Try `ISO-8859-1` as your character encoding. Does it work ?

Comment: @JonasCz I have checked, now more character looks like "?".

Comment: Try to download the HTML as a String, and parse that with Jsoup.

Comment: How can I download JSP like HTML?

Comment: Err, sorry. _Try to download the JSP as a String, and parse that with Jsoup._

Comment: I start class in main() method manually, work normal. But call in jsp or webservice look this issuses

Comment: Maybe the webserver is not configured correctly for utf-8 support ?  I hardly know anything of JSP, so i'm not much help..